# How to get the number of columns of a 2dimension array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 2 dimensional array `albumPhotos[x][y]`. The rows are `photoalbums` and the columns are `links to photos`.

Now every `photoalbum` has a different number of `photos` , that means that every `row` in this array has a different number of `columns`.

I am trying to check whats the length of every row in this array , that means how many columns every row has. How can i do that in javascript?

I tried :

```
for(var i=0; i< numberOfRows ; i++)
    for(var x=0; x < albumPhotos[i].length; x++) ...
```

but apparently this is wrong command in javascript. Then i tried something like this :

```
for(var i=0; i< numberOfRows ; i++)
    for(var x=0; x < albumPhotos.rows[i].cells.length; x++)
```

but it seems wrong again. I think this is for html tables and not for arrays.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why aren't you just adding `albumPhotos[i].length` to a variable in each iteration of your outer loop?

Comment: I dont see how that would solve the problem.. I get an error when i use this in the for loop.Would it change if i used a variable before it? Is this correct syntax?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Do a `console.log(albumPhotos)` and see what's in it

Comment: What exactly is `numberOfRows`? Why don't you use `; i < albumPhotos.length;`?

Comment: Are you sure `numberOfRows` has the right value?

Comment: I dont understand why this question was so confusing. Bojangles , albumphotos is a 2 dimensional array. Every row is an album and every column of this row is a link to a photo. @Ian numberOfRows is the number of rwos of my 2 dimensional table albumPhotos[x][y].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to check the `.length` of the current row.

```
var numberOfRows = albumPhotos.length;

for(var i=0; i < numberOfRows ; i++)
    console.log(albumPhotos[i].length);
```

---

And you're right, the second example is for table elements, not Arrays.

Comment: albumPhotos is a 2dimensional array , albumPhotos[x][y]. Every row is an album and every column of this row , is a link to a photo. So my question was how to count the length (eg the number of columns) of each row , of a 2dimensional array..

Comment: @JohnyJaz: Right. That's what this does. Unless you're saying you have Arrays, and you really have Objects. You've not provided a sample of the data, so we're relying entirely on your description.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let x = [
    [2,3,4],
    [1,1,1]
];
console.log(x.length)  // row count: 2
console.log(x[0].length) // column count: 3
```

just when u have same size for every row, since your guide is the first row to get your numbers of columns